# Identification of a kick sounding like "Sashay"(?) used in "Savah"(?)

Tags: technique

Can someone please refer me to a place where I can find out more on this particular kick. I do not know how to spell it. In the movie "Bruce Lee's real training film, rare footage with his own instructions and secrets!", one instructor refers to the "Sashay" used in "Savah". I would like to see more of this particular kick and style.

Comment: Perhaps Savate?

Comment: @mattm: Interesting, never heard of Savate before, although literally a "neighboring" art for me as a German.

Answer (score 7):

Based on mattm's comment, you may be looking for a *[chassé](https://savateaustralia.wordpress.com/essays/chasse/)* kick from *[Savate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savate)*.

There are several variations on the move, but I've found at least one reference to Bruce Lee's signature cross-over side kick coming from the [chassé-croisé](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMQn7GRkOqg) kick from Savate.